# How to insert multi dimensional data from a list to MYSQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql, list

I want to enter the values of `offer_title` and `Offer_details` into table `comp_offer_records`. Can someone please help.

```py
quotes =[{'Offer_Title': 'New credit ', 'Offer Details': 'The Centre'},
         {'Offer_Title': 'New credit1 ', 'Offer Details': 'The Centre1'}]
#If I flatten the list as below:
flat_list = [item for sublist in quotes for item in sublist]

How do I then ensure values corressponding to Offer_Title and Offer Details get loaded into separate columns?
params = ['?' for item in flat_list]
sql    = 'INSERT INTO comp_offer_records (Offer_Title, Offer_Details) VALUES (%s, %s);' % ','.join(params)
mycursor.executemany(sql, flat_list)
```

However this gives error:

> sql    = 'INSERT INTO comp_offer_records (Offer_Title, Offer_Details) VALUES (%s, %s);' % ','.join(params)

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: `quote` variable is a list, not a dictionary you cannot call `keys()` on a list. You need to change the approach

Comment: Please don't radically change your question after someone has answered.  Ask a new question instead, and consider accepting or upvoting the answer provided to this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
'(%s, %s);' % ','.join(params)
```

Expected 2 string arguments, when you passed 1

Replace it with

```
'(%s, %s);' % params
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is I do not know the exact number of lists. I have split lists using: res = [] 
for idx, sub in enumerate(quotes, start = 0): 
    if idx == 0: 
        #res.append(list(sub.keys())) 
        res.append(list(sub.values())) 
    else: 
        res.append(list(sub.values())) 
        
print("The converted list : " + str(res)). And then adding to DB using: mycursor.executemany("INSERT INTO comp_offer_records (Offer_Title, Offer_Details) VALUES(%s, %s)", str(res))

Comment: I was further able to add data to columns as below:sql = "INSERT INTO comp_offer_records (Offer_Title, Offer_Details) VALUES(%s, %s)"


mycursor.executemany(sql,res) Thanks all for help